# JavaFX.Пересечение границ фигур

Tags: java, javafx

Делается симуляция индикатора кругового обзора(радара). Есть отображение точек с затуханием и треугольник,который в виде сектора вращается,имитируя луч обзора.Необходимо,чтобы при пересечении границ треугольника и точки - точка появлялась на радаре.При вызове метода у треугольника  getBoundsInParent().intersects(Bounds bounds),то пересечение считается по прямоугольнику вокруг фигуры,а не по реальным границам.Как сделать,чтобы брались реальные границы фигуры?

Comment: Предоставьте, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код.

Comment: А просто сделать так, чтобы смотреть, попадают координаты точки в область треугольника нельзя?

Comment: попробуйте `javafx.scene.shape.Shape.intersect`, хотя в вашем случае можно просто посчитать два скалярных произведения, чтобы определить, что точка лежит между двумя сторонами треугольника

Comment: @zRrr спасибо огромное!Выручили!)